# How do I post a message to Yammer with a specific topic using the API?

Tags: api, yammer

I've got an application using the Yammer API, and I have a specific topic that I'd like to apply to a message (I know it by topicid).

The API is incredibly unclear: https://developer.yammer.com/api/#messages-manipulating

```
>*topicn*
>
>Topics to apply to the message. Can use topic1 through topic20.
```

If I send a message with

```
topic1:1234567
```

Where the number is a topicid. I get a message with a topic entitled the topic number.

Any idea what the syntax is to get the topic to match that topicid instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with the documentation as well - for me, the following worked: "body=A message with topics #foo #bar". In other words, the topics are the actual tags. Note that depending on the media type you set, certain characters (such as ";") may be problematic in the string.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the API is unclear though. I've also had issues with topics with spaces in them (using HTML encoded chars), not showing up with other comments of the same tag, so avoid them

Answer (score 2):

You can both :

- add the tag in the message Body.

Exemple if your topic is "Software" and you add in the message Body #Software you will see that the topic Software has been added to your post but you will also see #Software as a link in the message body. Not fantastic...

- pass the topic in parameter

This is the correct syntax :

```
yam.platform.request(
   { 
      url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
      , method: "POST"
      , data: {
       "body" :  msg_value
      ,"group_id" : groupID
      ,topic1 : "Software"
     }
```

...

Doing it that way, you won't see the topic name in the post...This is much better :-)